# Post nested Json to spring controller

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Well I am trying to retrieve a nested json in spring controller and getting 400 (bad request) error.

JSON

```
{"AuthenticationInfo":
  {"loginId":"243324","password":"xyz"}
}
```

Controller

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers={"Accept=*/*","content-type=application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public MySubscriber getSubscriber(@RequestBody MyAuthentication myAuthentication) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "getSubscriber");

        System.out.println("getSubscriber method : "+myAuthentication);


        MySubscriber mySubscriber = helloWebService.getSubscriber(myAuthentication);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "mySubscriber : " + mySubscriber);
        System.out.println( "mySubscriber : " + mySubscriber);
        return mySubscriber;
    }
```

MyAuthentication

```
public class MyAuthentication extends AuthenticationInfo {
    private AuthenticationInfo AuthenticationInfo;

    public AuthenticationInfo getAuthenticationInfo() {
        return AuthenticationInfo;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo) {
        AuthenticationInfo = authenticationInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "AuthenticationInfo : "+AuthenticationInfo;
    }
}
```

AuthenticationInfo

```
    public class AuthenticationInfo {
        private String loginId;
        private String password;
        public String getLoginId() {
            return loginId;
        }
        public void setLoginId(String loginId) {
            this.loginId = loginId;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "{ loginId : "+loginId+" || password"+password+"}";
        }
    }
```

The error goes when I fire just simple Json and retrieve it accordingly. The only issue here is a nested structure of the Json

Comment: post your error as well.

Comment: I am Hitting request using rest Client and getting this error

HTTP Status 400 -

type Status report

message

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (). JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final

Nothing on console

Comment: how bout debugging? can you do the debug and check which line cause the error.

Comment: I have debugged it and got to know the reason @RequestBody is unable to parse Nested Json. If i try to parse a normal json , with just property and not objects with in then it works fine

Comment: Why are you using MyAuthentication instead of AuthenticationInfo in the getSubscriber method

Comment: That is my implementation of service. Point is I am not even reaching to that point in code. My controller rejects a request at @RequestBody itself

Comment: You should try binding to AuthenticationInfo first and see if that works, and then try MyAuthentication

Comment: `@RequestBody` is perfectly capable of parsing nested JSON, however you have to adhere to the Java Beans specification. Your `MyAuthentication` doesn't have a field `AuthenticationInfo` it has a field `authenticationInfo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now whatever I am going to say might sound stupid. I am not sure if this is the behavior only with jackson or any other JSON library as well.

It will work and I have tested it, you just need to change the case of the private property declared in MyAuthentication class. Use something like below:

```
private AuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo;
```

Now you also have to change the request to match the case, so use the below:

```
{"authenticationInfo":{"loginId":"abcsdsd","password":"adsfsdfsdbcsdsd"}}
```

This works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try to modify `MyAuthentication` like this

```
    public static class MyAuthentication extends AuthenticationInfo {
    @JsonProperty("AuthenticationInfo")
    private AuthenticationInfo AuthenticationInfo;

    public IndexController.AuthenticationInfo getAuthenticationInfo() {
        return AuthenticationInfo;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationInfo(IndexController.AuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo) {
        AuthenticationInfo = authenticationInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AuthenticationInfo : " + AuthenticationInfo;
    }
}
```

Jackson's default jsoin properties start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it worked. And i needed this work around cause I dint had control over the rest request we firring