# Send nested object to Spring POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this JSON String send by Angular:

```
{
   "transaction_id": "1234",
   "usage": "Test Usage",
   "billing_address": {
      "first_name": "name",
      "last_name": "name",
      "address1": "street 1234",
      "zip_code": "11923"
   },
   "shipping_address": {
      "first_name": "name",
      "last_name": "name",
      "address1": "street 1234",
      "zip_code": "11923"
   }  
}
```

Java code:

```
public class DTO {

    private String transaction_id;
    private String usage;
    private BillingAddress billingAddress;
    private ShippingAddress shippingAddress;

    ... getter/setter
}

public class BillingAddress {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address1;    
    private String zip_code;
    ... getter/setter
}

public class ShippingAddress {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address1;    
    private String zip_code;
    ... getter/setter
}
```

Spring endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
      public ResponseEntity<?> handleWpfMessage(@PathVariable("id") id,
              @RequestBody DTO data){
        ....
}
```

What is the proper way to map the inner objects for `billing_address` and `shipping_address` in order values to be mapped properly? Do I need to add annotations in order to map them properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post nested Json to spring controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527046/post-nested-json-to-spring-controller)

Comment: Why don't you just try and then do some conclusions? The one thing I see is that your fields names don't satisfy java naming convention, and there's a simple way to solve this just adding `JsonProperty("some_name")`.

Answer (score 3):

You should add the following annotations to your DTO class:

```
public class DTO {

    private String transaction_id;
    private String usage;

    @JsonProperty("billing_address")
    private BillingAddress billingAddress;

    @JsonProperty("shipping_address")
    private ShippingAddress shippingAddress;

    ... getter/setter
}
```

Comment: Can I use the same object  for `BillingAddress` and `ShippingAddress` becasue as you can see the y have the same attributes?

Comment: Yes, you can. If these classes are the same, I would replace them with ```Address``` class. The annotations will work the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your angular client uses snake case. In order to make jackson deserializing properly you can configure it globally with :

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
```

However you can also configure it for a specific class :

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class DTO {
}
```

Comment: But I need also to add     `@JsonProperty("billing_address")` ?

Comment: no, as with snake case strategy jackson will serialize "billing_address" property to billingAddress field, in the same way for the other fields.

Comment: by the way, naming convention in java for naming fields is camel case. Ex : private String transactionId. Please refer to : https://dzone.com/articles/whats-in-a-name-java-naming-conventions

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can use the Jackson property mapping annotaion in your `DTO` class.

```
@JsonProperty("billing_address")
private BillingAddress billingAddress;
```

This means, in the json, attribute `billing_address` will be assigned to `billingAddress` variable.